# How to set selector correctly by refering to its contents and array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create html tables,and I would like to add class by reffering to `arr` and `its content`

When I set selector,I suffer 2 problems.

①`$( "td:contains('2')" )` selector select like `2`,`12`,`22`・・・・ my desired result is to select only `2`

② I prepared `arr` and I would like to write more simply by using `arr`.

My desired result is to add class of `arr` cells.

Is it simple way to achieve it?

Thanks

```js
const arr=[1,2,10,11,14]

$( "td:contains('1')" ).addClass('aqua')
$( "td:contains('2')" ).addClass('aqua')
$( "td:contains('10')" ).addClass('aqua')
$( "td:contains('11')" ).addClass('aqua')
$( "td:contains('14')" ).addClass('aqua')
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.aqua {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=calendar></div>


<script>
  let html = ''
  html += '<table>';
  let i = 0;
  for (let w = 0; w < 10; w++) {
    html += '<tr>';
    for (let d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
      i = i + 1;
      html += '<td data-layer=0>' + '<div>' + i + '</div>' + '</td>'
    }
    html += '</tr>';
  }
  html += '</table>'
  document.querySelector('#calendar').innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:contains` can't search for an exact match, it'll just search for if the element contains the text somewhere. If you want the text to match exactly, after selecting the elements, `filter` them by whether their `.text() === '2'`:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 10, 11, 14].map(String);

/*
const getExactMatch = text => function() { return $(this).text() === text };
$("td").filter(getExactMatch('1')).addClass('aqua');
$("td").filter(getExactMatch('2')).addClass('aqua');

or:
*/

$("td")
  .filter(function() { return arr.includes($(this).text()); })
  .addClass('aqua');
```

```css
td {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border: solid black 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.aqua {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=calendar></div>


<script>
  let html = ''
  html += '<table>';
  let i = 0;
  for (let w = 0; w < 10; w++) {
    html += '<tr>';
    for (let d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
      i = i + 1;
      html += '<td data-layer=0>' + '<div>' + i + '</div>' + '</td>'
    }
    html += '</tr>';
  }
  html += '</table>'
  document.querySelector('#calendar').innerHTML = html;
</script>
```